# iOS self taught developer transitioning to Android

Tags: android, ios

Hi I've been making iOS apps for about 3 1/2 years, I'm self taught and basically learnt how to program iOS apps by trial and error & youtube. I want to have my apps available on android because I've started making a lot of sales and want to expand my market, where is the best place to start?

Comment: This question is a bit overly broad, but have a look at:  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Comment: Is it possible to use the xcode IDE to develop for android? and how different is the programming language?

Comment: Picking up an android book is a good option too..

Comment: The easiest IDE to use is Eclipse as that is what google recommends and the Android SDK integrates easiest into.

Comment: what android book would you recommend. I've had a few iOS books what would be the best for android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand very clearly how the android activity lifecycle works, and look a lot into the style guide. Android is a whole different look/feel/style from iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I would do whatever worked for you before, that's always a formula for success. Trial and error & youtube. I would recommend long articles and books but it sounds like you learn best the way you mentioned.

http://www.youtube.com/user/androiddevelopers